Understanding Power Curves and Non-Monotonic Power Increase with Sample Size using simr
I’m working on a mixed-effects model to analyze
Reaction Time ~ Ethnicity * Identity + (1 | id)

using R. Ethnicity and Identity are effect-coded categorical variables (+1/-1), and the dependent variable follows an inverse Gaussian distribution.
What I Did:

Simulated Data: Extended the dataset to 250 participants. Added random intercepts to simulate realistic variability in the random effects.
Power Analysis: Simulated power for several effect sizes (e.g., -0.1, -0.5, -1, -1.67) using simr. Notably, the interaction term in the original model was not significant.
The Problem: In the power curves, power doesn’t consistently increase as the sample size increases. For example, power sometimes plateaus or even decreases slightly with larger sample sizes.

set.seed(111)
n_participants <- 150 

extended_data <- data_clean %>%
  slice(rep(1:n(), length.out = n() * n_participants / 
  length(unique(data_clean$id)))) %>%
  mutate(id = rep(1:n_participants, length.out = n()))

set.seed(111)  
extended_data <- extended_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    random_intercept = rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(16.5^2)),  
      # Adjust variance as needed
    Reaction_time = Reaction_time + random_intercept
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

model_updated <- glmer(
  Reaction_time ~ Ethnicity * identity + (1 | id),
  data = extended_data,
  family = inverse.gaussian(link = "identity"),
  control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", 
  optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e5))
)  

enerating power curve for Negative Effect size: -0.5 
Calculating power at 6 sample sizes along id
Power for predictor 'Ethnicity1:identity1', 
(95% confidence interval),
=======================================|
by largest value of id:
    100: 82.00% (73.05, 88.97) - 2814 rows
    110: 84.00% (75.32, 90.57) - 3094 rows
    120: 91.00% (83.60, 95.80) - 3374 rows
    130: 80.00% (70.82, 87.33) - 3654 rows
    140: 78.00% (68.61, 85.67) - 3934 rows
    150: 82.00% (73.05, 88.97) - 4214 rows

Time elapsed: 0 h 8 m 47 s

 Generating power curve for Negative Effect size: -1.67 
 Calculating power at 6 sample sizes along id
 Power for predictor 'Ethnicity1:identity1', 
     (95% confidence interval),   
 =======================================|
 by largest value of id:
    100: 85.00% (76.47, 91.35) - 2814 rows
    110: 85.00% (76.47, 91.35) - 3094 rows
    120: 83.00% (74.18, 89.77) - 3374 rows
    130: 79.00% (69.71, 86.51) - 3654 rows
    140: 84.00% (75.32, 90.57) - 3934 rows
    150: 78.00% (68.61, 85.67) - 4214 rows

Time elapsed: 0 h 10 m 12 s

current script-
# Load Required Libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(simr)

set.seed(123)

model_current <- glmer(
  Reaction_time ~ Ethnicity * identity + (1 | id),
  data = data_clean,
  family = inverse.gaussian(link = "identity"),
  control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", 
              optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e5))
)

summary(model_current)

set.seed(123)

model_extended <- extend(
  model_current,
  along = "id",
  n = 150
)

extended_data <- getData(model_extended)
n_distinct_participants <- n_distinct(extended_data$id)

print(table(extended_data$id))

model_updated <- glmer(
  Reaction_time ~ Ethnicity * identity + (1 | id),
  data = extended_data,
  family = inverse.gaussian(link = "identity"),
  control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", 
              optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e5))
)

summary(model_updated)
VarCorr(model_updated)
VarCorr(model_updated)$id[1] <- 1200  # lowering random intercept variance
varr
power_result <- powerSim(
  model_updated,
  test = fixed("Ethnicity1:identity1"),
  nsim = 1000  
)

print(power_result)

saveRDS(power_result, file = "power_sim_150_2212.rds")

set.seed(123)

power_curve <- powerCurve(
  model_updated,
  test = fixed("Ethnicity1:identity1"),
  along = "id",
  breaks = seq(100, 150, by = 10),  
  nsim = 500  
)

plot(power_curve)

print(power_curve)
saveRDS(power_curve, file = "power_curve_150_2212.rds")

model_extended_250 <- extend(
  model_current,
  along = "id",
  n = 250
)

extended_data_250 <- getData(model_extended_250)

n_distinct_participants_250 <- n_distinct(model_extended_250$id)

model_updated_250 <- glmer(
  Reaction_time ~ Ethnicity * identity + (1 | id),
  data = extended_data_250,
  family = inverse.gaussian(link = "identity"),
  control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", 
              optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e5))
)

summary(model_updated_250)
power_result_250 <- powerSim(
  model_updated_250,
  test = fixed("Ethnicity1:identity1"),
  nsim = 1000
)

print(power_result_250)

power_curve_250 <- powerCurve(
  model_updated_250,
  test = fixed("Ethnicity1:identity1"),
  along = "id",
  breaks = seq(100, 250, by = 25),
  nsim = 500
)

plot(power_curve_250)

print(power_curve_250)

# Step 11: Inspect Final Dataset Distribution
table(extended_data_250$Ethnicity, extended_data_250$identity)

# Step 12: Check Fixed Effects in Simulated Data
extended_data_250 %>%
  group_by(Ethnicity, identity) %>%
  summarise(mean_rt = mean(Reaction_time), .groups = "drop")



I don't have an answer, just a note that the same thing happens in much simpler models. I remember seeing this for estimating binomial proportions, but I can't think of the cite right now. I think it was an article by Agresti, but I could be wrong.

I don't see the code for your simr call in your post, can you add it? My initial suspicion is that you aren't running enough simulations per sample size to get stable estimates, or something else with the powerSim() call. But of course Peter is right that sometimes power behaves non-intuitively in simple cases, and multilevel models behave non-intuitively as a rule :)

Hi Noa. It would be useful to share your complete code as suggested above, because when trying to run your code in R, I get various messages about non-existing functions. I think that @PeterFlom might be referring to this article https://doi.org/10.1198/000313002317572835 (there's an illustration of the problem here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/644590/). However, another explanation is possible, as suggested by wzbillings: the number of simulations you used was possibly insufficient. Try increasing it, and see if it solves the problem.

Thank you all. I uploaded my current script

One remaining issue is that you don't provide data_clean, so we cannot execute the code.

This is more of a comment because I'm not sure what the problem is either, but in practice, I've found that with simr, it's often easier to use the fcompare function to test the power for an interaction. So you could try
power_result <- powerSim(model_updated, 
                        test = fcompare(Reaction_time ~ Ethnicity1 + identity1), 
                        nsim = 1000)


And the curve

power_curve_250 <- powerCurve(
  model_updated_250,
  test = fcompare(Reaction_time ~ Ethnicity1 + identity1),
  along = "id",
  breaks = seq(100, 250, by = 25),
  nsim = 500
)

